# SSIS: failed to retrieve long data / truncation errors

Tags: excel, import, ssis, export

I'm getting either of those two errors when trying to export data from a set of excel spreadsheets.
Simplified scenario:

- two excel spreadsheets containing 1 text column
- in file 1 the text is never longer than 200 characters
- in the 2nd - it is.

SSIS suppose to import them automatically from a folder - easy and simple, but...
Excel source component decides what data type is used here.

When, using created by me sample file with sample text data,  it decides to use DT_WSTR(255) it fails with the second file with the truncation error.

When I force it to use DT_NTEXT (by creating longer text in the sample file) if fails with the 1st file complaining that "Failed to retrieve long data for column"... because the 1st file doesn't contain longer texts...

Has anybody found a solution/work-around for this? I mean - except manually changing the source data?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to change a registry setting, TypeGuessRows: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2770/importing-data-from-excel-using-ssis-part-1/

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz - there is no point to do that. What it does is checks all your data when set to 0 (well, not all - up to a certain no of rows - don't remember the exact number). The case here is that it is known already how long those text entries are. The problem is the "decision" made by the excel source... it is OK for one file but not for the other, and they are being imported by the same automated process...

Comment: The thing is that it’s making the decision based on the first 8 rows by default. The second file has different data in the first 8 rows vs the first file. Excel is making an incorrect decision in that case. Forcing it to look at the whole column will prevent it from changing the datatype. I’d give this a try, it’s a common problem in working with excel files and this is a reliable way of getting excel to return the correct datatype.

Answer (score 0):

We can use Flat File Connection Manager instead of Excel Connection Manager. When we create Flat File Connection Manager we can set data type and length explicitly. To do so first we need to save the excel file as csv file or tab delimited file. Then we can use this file to create Flat File Connection. Drag and drop a Flat File Source in  the Data Flow tab. In the Flat File Source Editor dialog box click New button and it will launches  Flat File Connection Manager Editor dialog box. In the General tab specify the file full path and click Advanced tab. Then put data type and column width like below image.
[image]

Click OK and close the dialog box, this will create our connection manager. Now the connection manager can successfully read the full length data but we have to set the data type & length of the Output Columns so that we can get the data in the output pipeline. To do that right click on the Flat File Source and click Show Advanced Editor option. Then follow the below image instruction.
[image]

When we finish we run our package and it run successfully without any truncation error and insert all the data in our target database.

Comment: Does this mean that you need to convert your excel file each time to run the package on or once set up you can run this on your excel just fine?